# Does terminology for changes in membrane potential refer to additive or multiplicative change?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, proteins, brain

Is the membrane potential **just the number of mV**, or is it **to what extent it differs from 0**?

For example: If the mV goes from -40 to -60, can you say that:

- The membrane potential decreases, because the number of mV decreases (from -40 to -60)
  **or**
- The membrane potential increases, because the difference to 0 increases (from 40 to 60)?

Comment: Short hint: It is same as [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential), as we study in physics. with the same unit Volt, with magnitude adjusted with metric prefix (milli, micro, nano, pico etc), with positive ($+$) or negative ($-$) value. The concept has been taken in [Electrochemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_potential)

Answer (score 1):

Note to others: this question appears to be about terminology rather than the biophysics behind the membrane potential.

When the terms "increase" and "decrease" are used relative to membrane potential, they refer to *additive changes in potential*, not to multiplicative change or effects on absolute value. The standard is to relate the potential inside to the potential outside of a cell (so a negative potential means the inside is more negative than the outside; potentials in biology are always relative, just like in physics).

Therefore, a membrane potential decrease means that the value of the potential becomes more negative, and a membrane potential increase means the value of the potential becomes more positive. The changes on the *absolute value* of the potential depend only on where you start from.

Other terms that are more clear to use are *hyperpolarization* and *depolarization*, where hyperpolarization always refers to the membrane potential becoming more negative than rest, and depolarization refers to the membrane potential becoming more positive than rest. *Repolarization* is also used, particularly in the context of action potentials, to refer to voltage changes in the direction of hyperpolarization when the cell is currently depolarized.